# Calls to Firestore are working locally from Shell but give empty error after deployed to Cloud Functions

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-admin-sdk, firebase-cli, firebase-tools

I am running queries on Firestore from Firebase Functions. Everything works fine when I run the function from a local shell.

However, after I deploy the code and call the function, Firestore is returning a blank error {} in production.

Firestore permissions should not be the issue here because it works locally.

Service Account should also not be the issue.

There is no error message or debug information. I have checked the Function logs on the server console as well.

```
firestore.collection("users").doc(uid).set(userJson, {merge:true})
    .then((done) => {
        console.log('Created new user');
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('Error creating new user:', JSON.stringify(err));
    });
```

Package.json

```
"engines": { "node": "8" }
```

I am expecting that the behavior to be the same after deployment as it was in the shell. How can I get the calls to Firestore work from Firebase Functions server?

Answer (score 1):

1. Check the **package.json** file in **/functions** folder (created by firebase init). Make sure you are using the latest supported version of NodeJS. As of 2020, it should be NodeJS 10:

   `"engines": {"node": "10"}`
2. Make sure you are using the latest version of **Firebase CLI**. As of 2020, it should be 8.10.0

   `npm install -g firebase-tools`

```
npm list -g --depth=0 
npm uninstall -g firebase-tools
npm install -g firebase-tools
npm list -g --depth=0
```

If it doesn't work, clean the cache first `npm cache clean --force` and then retry.

3. Make sure the payload you are passing into firestore queries does not have **blank keys** or **undefined values**.

```
firestore.collection("users").doc("123").set({
    id: 1234,
    '': 'something', // ERROR
    phone: undefined, // ERROR
    email: 'user@email.com'
})
```

4. Firestore calls are **asynchronous** (they return a Promise). Make sure you are not returning the response `response.send()` before the Firestore call is complete. Use `async/await` or `.then()` properly.

Note: You probably don't need to explicitly configure the **Admin SDK Service Account**, because the default service accounts already have permission to access Firestore from Cloud Functions.